# Automapper reflection error with Json.Net JObject

Tags: c#, json.net, automapper

I'm getting a reflection error when using AutoMapper with a json.net JObject

```
public class Source
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public JObject Value { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the target

```
public class Target
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public JObject Value { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the mapping

```
public class SourceTargetMapping
{
    public static void IntializeMapping()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<Target, Source>()
            .ForMember(g => g.Value, op => op.ResolveUsing(s => s.Value));

        Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Target>()
            .ForMember(s => s.Value, op => op.ResolveUsing(g => g.Value));
    }

}

public static class SourceTargetMappingExtensions
{
    public static Source ToDomain(this Target repoItem)
    {
        var result = Mapper.Map<Target, Source>(repoItem);
        return result;
    }

    public static Target ToRepo(this Source domainItem)
    {
        var result = Mapper.Map<Source, Target>(domainItem);
        return result;
    }

    public static List<Source> ToDomain(this ICollection<Target> repoCollection)
    {
        return Mapper.Map<ICollection<Target>, List<Source>>(repoCollection);
    }

    public static List<Target> ToRepo(this ICollection<Source> domainCollection)
    {
        return Mapper.Map<ICollection<Source>, List<Target>>(domainCollection);
    }

}
```

Here is the (NUnit) unit test (the ones with non empty values fail, empty values pass)

```
[TestFixture]
public class AutoMappingTest
{
  [SetUp]
  public void SetUp()
  {
    SourceTargetMapping.IntializeMapping();
    Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
  }

  [TestCase("State", "{\"State\":\"TX\"}", "Should handle normal value")]
  [TestCase("State", @"{""State"":""TX""}", "double quoted quotes")]
  [TestCase("State", "", "empty json")]
  [TestCase("State", null, "null json")]
  public void ShouldMapFromSourceToTarget(string key, string value, string description)
  {
    //arrange
    JObject jObject = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) ? JObject.Parse(value) : new JObject();
    var source = new Source() {Key = key, Value = jObject};

    //act
    var repo = source.ToRepo();

    Assert.IsNotNull(repo);
    Assert.AreEqual(key, repo.Key);
  }
```

And here is the exception:

```
AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException : 

Mapping types:
JObject -> JObject
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject -> Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject

Destination path:
Target.Value

Source value:
{
  "State": "TX"
}
  ----> System.Reflection.TargetException : Object does not match target type.
at IsolationChamber.SourceTargetMappingExtensions.ToRepo(Source domainItem) in SourceTargetMapping.cs: line 62
at IsolationChamberTest.AutoMappingTest.ShouldMapFromSourceToTarget(String key, String value, String description) in AutoMapperSiteSettingTest.cs: line 35
--TargetException
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.CheckConsistency(Object target)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, Object[] index)
at AutoMapper.Mappers.DictionaryMapper.Map(ResolutionContext context, IMappingEngineRunner mapper)
at AutoMapper.MappingEngine.AutoMapper.IMappingEngineRunner.Map(ResolutionContext context)
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: You posted the code of `SiteSettingMapping` but your test using `SourceTargetMapping`, is it a typo? And can you post the code for `SourceTargetMappingExtensions.ToRepo`?

Comment: I posted an update to the mapping code in the question. thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same issue, just add an explicit mapping JObject -> JObject which makes a clone.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<JObject, JObject>().ConvertUsing(value =>
{
    if (value == null)
        return null;

    return new JObject(value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was not doing the mapping correctly.  I created a custom type converter per AutoMapper's [documentation](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-type-converters) and then it worked.